# Hide users list and form entries in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, forms, privacy, ws, wpforms

I am new to WordPress. We are developing a website for our medical startup. We would like patients to fill a form. However, we need the information in this form and the users list to be hidden from the administrator (us). Only a doctor with a unique key should be able to see this information, due to privacy regulations.

I already tried the typical plugins: WPForms, WS Forms, etc. Hiding entry forms from the administrator seems impossible. Hiding the users list even more so.

Could you please tell me if you have any idea to make this work? Is there maybe some specific plugin for this which I am not aware of?

Thanks a lot!

I tried the typical plugins: WPForms, WS Forms, but none of them has an y option to hide the entries from the administrator. Plugins to regular which page users have access to cannot hide pages from the administrator, since the administrator could at any time revoke these restrictions.